# $χ (y) ≡ |M|\pmod p $. This is an immediate consequence of the fact $|M| ≡ |M^P| \pmod p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, representation-theory

Let $p$ be a prime, $P$ a finite $p$-group and $M$ a finite $P$-set.
Suppose that $k$ is an integral domain of characteristic zero. Denote by $χ$ the
character of the permutation $kP$-module $kM$. For any $y ∈ P$ we have $χ (y) ≡
|M| \pmod p$. This is an immediate consequence of the fact $|M| ≡ |M^P| \pmod p$.

I've been thinking this for quite a while. How this is immediate? Is there a connection between fixed point of the p-group and of an element? Thank you!

Comment: The character of a permutation representation is the number of fixed points.

Comment: yes, and then what should i do? thx!

Comment: i'm being silly here.

Comment: the subgroup generated by $y$ also acts on the set.

Comment: i am thinking along your line...

Comment: i might have it.$ |M^{<y>}|$ congruent to $|M| (mod p)$ and the numbers of elements fixed by the group generated by y are the same , if I am correct...

Comment: Yes, that is correct.